# Copy/Paste apps script Execution Completed but returns no results

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which was working fine, both manually and on time trigger.

However, it starts to return nothing after a day even though it says execution is completed.
In the execution log it appears to be running fine every hour but does not return any results.

The intended use was to check for all rows in Column U for value of "1", copy the values of specific columns from Spreadsheet A, and paste it on the next available row of Spreadsheet B.

Here's the code:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var check = "1"; 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("A");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("B");
  var values = copySheet.getRange("A2:U" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[20] == check).map(r => [3, 4, 6, 11, 20, 21].map(e => r[e - 1]));
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I tried the code on my end with some dummy data and it works. 

1) Can you check if any anything has changed in your sheet like any new column added or deleted because of which the data in column "U" has moved to some other position. 

2) Secondly, check if the column "U" actually contains the value "1" in at least one row. If not, then this is expected result to return nothing.

Comment: It worked all of a sudden few hours ago. I think I've reached the daily quota, that was why it returned nothing. Thanks!